# IKernel не могу найти сборку

Tags: c#, asp.net, ninject

Начинаю изучать ASP.NET. После установки Ninject MVC3 и Ninject появился файл NinjectWebCommon.cs, но в нём ошибки связанные с IKernel:

> "Не удалось найти имя типа или пространства имен "IKernel".Пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку?.

Соответственно, проект не запускается. Поиск в интернете к сожалению не дал результатов. Пожалуйста подскажите куда и что добавить?

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(test_web.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(test_web.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]
namespace test_web.App_Start
{
using System;
using System.Web;

using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;

using Ninject;
using Ninject.Web.Common;

public static class NinjectWebCommon 
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the application
    /// </summary>
    public static void Start() 
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Stop()
    {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        try
        {
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

            RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }
        catch
        {
            kernel.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
    }        
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял из этого [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10316885/7198805)
 то вы питаетесь одновременно использовать `NinjectHttpApplication` и `App_Start` нужно выберать один.Что бы правильно использовать `Ninject` почитайте [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/21.2.php)

Comment: Проблема не была решена, этим способом.

Comment: @БогданШарков  добавьте в вопрос ваш код из `Web.config`  скореевсего у вас там не согласие с версиями фреамворка

Comment: Проблема была решена с помощью пересоздания проекта.

Comment: @БогданШарков тогда нужно быть внимательнее ;)